# Wierd binary arithmetic using 2's complement

Tags: binary

Please move this question to other stackexchange site if its not the part of SO.

If i subtract 1110 from 1001 using 2's complement method, then the result is (-)1011 . But it should have been (-)101 . Why does this happen? Is 2's complement method is inadequate? Or there's something i'm missing?

Comment: You're expecting -5 and you're getting -5 (1011 is -5 in 4bit 2's complement). What's the problem here?

Comment: @harold : isn't 1011 equal to 11 ?

Comment: Yes, but you're doing this in 4 bits, so modulo 16, and then 11 = -5 (mod 16). You can see that by doing, say, 6 + 11 (result: 1, so it's like doing 6 - 5)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I didn't knew negative numbers were represented a bit different on 2's complement. It seems that negative numbers in 2's complement are represented such that it yields 0 when added to the additive inverse.

More on : academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/2s_comp.htm